# Canvas Mouse Positioning Incorrect in IE10

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, canvas, internet-explorer-10

I am having an issue with Internet Explorer 10 not properly registering the location of the mouse on the `<canvas>` element if it is not up against the top of the page. Open up IE10 and look at the links below.

---

**The problem:**

Click on this link and try dragging the nodes of the graph around:
http://ffi-server.no-ip.biz:257/test/good.html

Now, try the same thing on this page: http://ffi-server.no-ip.biz:257/test/bad.html

Interestingly, IE9 does not have this issue, and adding a `<meta>` tag to tell IE10 to render the page as IE9 does not solve this issue.

---

**Possible solution?**

I think I have found the problematic line of code, I just can't figure out how to correct it. Look at line `3044` in: http://pastebin.com/82GJBiEB

I just don't know how to correct it. I believe that IE10 is reporting a different `e.pageY` value than browsers which are working correctly. You can verify that by clicking on different areas of the canvas on this page: http://ffi-server.no-ip.biz:257/test/alert.html and see the reported values in IE10 and, say. Chrome.

---

Could anyone suggest a way to correct this issue?

Thank you for your time!

Comment: you are using jQuery, so you need to rule it out as the cause of the bug.  In addition to displaying `e.pageY`, display `e.originalEvent.pageY` to see if maybe jQuery is "correcting" the value incorrectly.

Comment: @Brandon I found out later, jQuery IS the bug: http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/12343. It cannot properly calculate the position of the mouse in IE10.

Answer (score 0):

Try e.layerX, and e.layerY. I had a similar issue, and this fixed it.